# How to get numbers from contacts in android

Tags: android, arraylist, autocomplete, cursor, contacts

I have a autosuggestion where i want user to only put his/her contact name then show the suggestion of matching contacts .... but when user press the submit button then the respective number of that contact should be captured

Plz post the code not links

I have successfully shown the names in autosuggestion

**Thanks guys**

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14809972/android-get-phone-number-from-contactlist

Comment: this could be helpful for you...


http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6107056/getting-all-phone-book-contact-details-into-an-array-in-android

Comment: just follow my own ans

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19972085/android-display-contacts-of-type-custom/19972249#19972249

Comment: that is not what i m lucking for.... i want 2 list one of names and other of numbers ... how to do that